# Distributed Drill Won't Start: "Drillbit is disallowed to bind to loopback address in distributed mode."

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-drill

I have (3) CentOS8 VirtualBox VM's, with networking enabled and each with 16 GB RAM allocated. Each has `/etc/hosts` configured as such:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

I am running a Zookeeper Quorum across the VMs with the following config:

```
#/home/strickolas/Downloads/project/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
clientPort=2181
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/home/strickolas/Downloads/project/zookeeper/data
reconfigEnabled=true
standaloneEnabled=false
server.1=192.168.0.4:2888:3888
server.2=192.168.0.5:2888:3888
server.3=192.168.0.6:2888:3888
```

I killed the firewall using `sudo systemctl stop firewalld`. It was causing me problems with running ZK. I will eventually need to config the firewall properly, but for now, that's a future-me problem.

Doing a `./bin/zkServer.sh status` says that ZK is running as it should be:

```
Zookeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config /home/strickolas/Downloads/project/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Client port found: 2181. Client address:localhost.
Mode: leader  # or follower depending on which node you ask.
```

Now for my **Drill setup**:

```
#/home/strickolas/Downloads/project/drill/conf/drill-override.conf
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "drillbits1",
  zk.connect: "192.168.0.4:2181,192.168.0.5:2181,192.168.0.6:2181"
}
```

Running `./bin/drillbit.sh run` results in:

```
Tue Mar 31: 23:59:16 EDT 2020 Starting drillbit on localhost.localdomain
core file size            (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size             (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority               (-e) 0
file size                 (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                   (-i) 63366
max locked memory         (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size           (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                        (-n) 1024
pipe size              (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues       (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority                (-r) 0
stack size                (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time                 (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes                (-u) 63366
virtual memory            (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                        (-x) unlimited
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.drill.exec.exception.DrillbitStartupException: Failure during initial startup of Drillbit.
  at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:584)
  at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:550)
  at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.main(Drillbit.java:546)
Caused by: org.apache.drill.exec.exception.DrillbitStartupException: Drillbit is disallowed to bind to loopback address in distributed mode.
  at org.apache.drill.exec.service.ServiceEngine.start(ServiceEngine.java:97)
  at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.run(Drillbit.java:220)
  at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:580)
  ... 2 more
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an entry in /etc/hosts in each of the hosts with their IP address and their hostname (e.g. "192.168.0.4  drillbit1" for node 1,  "192.168.0.5  drillbit2" for node 2, and "192.168.0.6  drillbit3" for node 3).